# Extracting schema from Union Avro

Tags: java, hadoop, avro

I have the following union:

```
{
          "name" : "price",
          "type" : [ "null", {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "PriceType",
              "fields" : [ {
                "name" : "text_value",
                "type" : [ "null", "double" ],
                "source" : "element text_value"
              }, {
                "name" : "currency",
                "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
                "default" : null,
                "source" : "attribute currency"
              } ]
            }
          } ],
          "default" : null,
          "source" : "element price"
        }
```

From this union I get the schema of price field using this code:

```
Schema new_schema=schema.getField("price").schema();
```

Now I want to obtain the schema of the Union:

```
{
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "record",
              "name" : "PriceType",
              "fields" : [ {
                "name" : "text_value",
                "type" : [ "null", "double" ],
                "source" : "element text_value"
              }, {
                "name" : "currency",
                "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
                "default" : null,
                "source" : "attribute currency"
              }
```

How can I do this? And I How Do I insert a Union in a Record?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a union type you can extract the schema as follows: 
`new_schema.getTypes().get(0);`